# Adding in support lines to a 3D parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I've managed to plot a 3D parametric curve with `pgfplots`, but I'd like to add support lines to my plot to add depth i.e. vertical lines from the plot to the `xy`-plane. Does anybody know how to do this without manually adding in lines from various points on the curve?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
height=15cm,
width=15cm,
clip=false, 
axis lines = middle,
ticks=none,
xmin=-2,xmax=6,
ymin=-6,ymax=6,
zmin=-1,zmax=6,
] 

\addplot3 [only marks,mark=*] coordinates {(5,5,1) (1,5,2)};
\addplot3 [only marks,mark=x,mark size=3pt] coordinates {(-1,-5,5) (5,-2,2)};

\node[anchor=north] at (axis cs:5,5,1) {$(5,5,1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:-1,-5,5) {$(-1,-5,5)$};
\node[anchor=west] at (axis cs:5,-2,2) {$(5,-2,2)$};
\node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:1,5,2) {$(1,5,2)$};

\draw[dashed] (axis cs:5,5,1) -- (axis cs:-1,-5,5) -- (axis cs:5,-2,2) -- (axis cs:1,5,2);

\addplot3 [y domain=0:0,
domain=0:1,
samples=50,
variable=\t]({-22*t^3+36*t^2-18*t+5},{-9*t^3+39*t^2-30*t+5},{10*t^3-21*t^2+12*t+1});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a "dummy" plot using the `ycomb` feature. For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=15cm,
            width=15cm,
            clip=false,
            axis lines=middle,
            ticks=none,
            xmin=-2,xmax=6,
            ymin=-6,ymax=6,
            zmin=-1,zmax=6,
        ]

            % before plotting the "real" plot add the `ycomb' plot with a
            % reduced number of sample ploints
            \addplot3 [
                draw=black!25,
                y domain=0:0,
                domain=0:1,
                samples=11,
                variable=\t,
                ycomb,
            ] (
                {-22*t^3+36*t^2-18*t+5},
                {-9*t^3+39*t^2-30*t+5},
                {10*t^3-21*t^2+12*t+1}
            );
            % now plot the real line
            \addplot3 [
                y domain=0:0,
                domain=0:1,
                samples=50,
                variable=\t,
            ] (
                {-22*t^3+36*t^2-18*t+5},
                {-9*t^3+39*t^2-30*t+5},
                {10*t^3-21*t^2+12*t+1}
            );

            \addplot3 [only marks,mark=*] coordinates {(5,5,1) (1,5,2)};
            \addplot3 [only marks,mark=x,mark size=3pt] coordinates {(-1,-5,5) (5,-2,2)};

            \node [anchor=north] at (axis cs:5,5,1)   {$(5,5,1)$};
            \node [anchor=south] at (axis cs:-1,-5,5) {$(-1,-5,5)$};
            \node [anchor=west]  at (axis cs:5,-2,2)  {$(5,-2,2)$};
            \node [anchor=south] at (axis cs:1,5,2)   {$(1,5,2)$};

            \draw [dashed] (axis cs:5,5,1) -- (axis cs:-1,-5,5)
                -- (axis cs:5,-2,2) -- (axis cs:1,5,2);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]